# Asp.Net MVC: Allow the `DEL` character in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

I have Asp.Net MVC application (.NET Framework 4.8) with Web API controller and I need to allow the `DEL` character (ASCII character `127`, HX is `%7F`) in action's parameter in that controller. (In general I need to allow pretty much all ASCII characters from 32 to 127 but `/` and `\`).

My controller

```
public class ManagementController : ApiController
...
[HttpPost]
[Route("management/{paramater?}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string paramater = null)
{
}
```

In `web.config`, there is changed a list of invalid characters, since `<`, `>`, `&` and other characters can be present in value for `parameter`

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" requestPathInvalidCharacters="\" />
</system.web>
```

Also double escaping is allowed to enable plus `+` sign (yeah, it is considered dangerous setting) and added `ManagementUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0` handler to allow `.` in URL

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
  </security>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
         path="*."
         verb="*"
         type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
         preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="ManagementUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
         path="/management/*"
         verb="POST"
         type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
         preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Currently, when `parameter` contains percent-encoded reserved characters (e.g. !, *, :, +, etc. and others like `.`), routing works correctly and controller's action is getting expected `parameter` value (e.g. request is issued to URL `http://localhost/management/012345%2A` and `parameter` value is `012345*` in controller's action).

However when `parameter` contains `DEL` character in percent-encoded form `%7F` (e.g. request is issued to URL `http://localhost/management/012345%7F`), IIS returns `Bad Request`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Could you please advise on how to allow `DEL` character in URL in Asp.Net MVC application?

**UPDATE**
RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 does not specify `DEL` character as Reserved Character or Unreserved Character. However `DEL` character can be part of a URL in Asp.Net Core applications. Unfortunately this project cannot be moved to Asp.Net Core due to technical restrictions

Comment: Yes, POST request is send with percent-encoded `DEL` character `%7F` (e.g. `management/012345%7F`) and IIS responses with Bad Request

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where %7F will not work: (try it!)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/%7F
```

And here is an example where %7F will work: (try it!)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/?parameter=%7F
```

So change your code to:

```
public class ManagementController : ApiController
...
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Management(string parameter = null)
{
}
```